# Converting Hardware address to MAC address using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have hardware address in this form 0000.f0h0.111g and need to convert into MAC address 00:00:f0:h0:11:1g like this format using python.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Can you put the address into a variable as a string and then use the sub string functions of python to extract the parts you need? I am thinking that both the hardware address and MAC address are of fixed size. Is that right?

Comment: @bob yes they both are of same length just difference is in partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
   def convertFunc(mc):
        mc = mc.replace('.','')
        t = iter(mc)
        res = ':'.join(x+y for x,y in zip(t,t))
        return res
```